# Could you help me to identify this font?

Tags: macos, font

I'm looking to reproduce the font for the red text Selin ve Sercan to use on OS X.

It is very important to find this font's name for me. Does anyone know the exact name of this font?

[image]

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Another place to ask might be http://typophile.com/fontid

Answer (score 1):

According to [WhatFontIs](http://www.whatfontis.com), seems to be In And Out Black:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fenotype/in-and-out/black/

Comment: Though similar the uppercase S and the lowercase c are really different

Comment: And the lowercase e, and a, and n...really the only character that is similar is the lowercase r.

Comment: I just uploaded the photo and paste the results. Anyway, the quality of the photo is quite bad, so, trying with a better quality one, the site will present more accurate results.